# How can I map types in a class library without mapped classes leaking from that library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have a web project and a class library and I need to map types in the library, for example

```
namespace Library
{
   public class Type1 { ... }
   internal class Type2 { ... }

   public class Repository : IRepository
   {
      private readonly IMappingEngine mappingEngine;

      public Repository(..., IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
      {
         this.mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
         ...
      }

      public void Add(Type1 type1)
      {
         var type2 = this.mappingEngine.Map<Type1, Type2>(type1);
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Here Type1 is a domain model type whereas Type2 is an EF entity object (they're both in the same namespace here for brevity's sake). Now in my repository I'd like to map Type1 to Type2 using AutoMapper. The catch is, I can only create maps using the static Mapper. If I were to do that in the web project, I'd have to make the EF classes (e.g. Type2) public so the web project can see them (EF types leak to the web project). Of course, I could invoke Mapper.CreateMap inside the Repository, but that doesn't feel right.

Anybody got an idea what to do about it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the web project? It's model manipulation: it ought to reside entirely within the model library.

Comment: Exactly, but where am I supposed to call CreateMap<…>()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to declare a static method inside the Library project, such as

```
namespace Library.Infrastructure.AutoMapper
{
   public static class Configuration
   {
      public static void MapTypes()
      {
         Mapper.CreateMap<Type2, Type1>()
            .ConstructUsing(t => new Type1(t.Guid, ...));

         ...
      }
   }
}
```

which I can then call from my AutoMapper setup in my web project like so:

```
namespace Web
{
   public class AutoMapperConfig
   {
      public static void MapTypes(...)
      {
         ...

         Library.Infrastructure.AutoMapper.Configuration
            .MapTypes();
      }
   }
}
```

That way I can map types at startup without the types in Library leaking into the web project or having to map types inside the repository.